# Get/Set coordinates for UV vertices using Python

Tags: python, uv

I got this UV map, and I want to set the position coordinates for all the four vertices to `x=0.5` and `y=0.5` *(in the center of the green pixel)*.

I've already tried to use `bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0,0,0))`, but this moves the vertices relative to the current position. **Is there a way to set specific coordinates/position for the UV vertices?**

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The uv coordinates are stored in 'loops':

You set `ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop_index].uv = (0.5, 0.5)`

You can see how loops work here:

```
# Loops per face
for face in ob.data.polygons:
    for vert_idx, loop_idx in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
        uv_coords = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop_idx].uv
        print("face idx: %i, vert idx: %i, uvs: %f, %f" % (face.index, vert_idx, uv_coords.x, uv_coords.y))

# Or just cycle all loops
for loop in ob.data.loops :
    uv_coords = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop.index].uv
    print(uv_coords)
```

Comment: and ob = bpy.context.active_object