# How to assign uv-coordinates to a procedurally generated mesh

Tags: python, mesh, uv

How do i assign UV coordinates to a procedurally generated mesh. All the examples in the blender wiki cover versions of blender older than `2.7`.

In example the snippet

```
def createTextureLayer(name, me, texFaces):
        uvtex = me.uv_textures.new()
        uvtex.name = name
        for n,tf in enumerate(texFaces):
            datum = uvtex.data[n]
            datum.uv1 = tf[0]
            datum.uv2 = tf[1]
            datum.uv3 = tf[2]
        return uvtex
```

results in

```
AttributeError: 'MeshTexturePoly' object has no attribute 'uv1'
```

What should I do?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30679/2271

Comment: see also the template Text Editor -> Templates -> Python -> Mesh Operator UV

Comment: sections in the api manual: [bpy.types.Mesh - example code](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=types.mesh#mesh-data), [bmesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_1/bmesh.html#customdata-access)